# Compile a TF Javascript model for Google Coral Edge TPU module

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, google-coral, tflite, edge-tpu

I'd like to run a precompiled Google Teachable Machine TF Javascript model on a Raspberry Pi with an USB Google Coral Edge TPU module.

I've compiled a Colab Notebook ([this](https://github.com/mongoq/thesis/blob/main/MahmutGuelerce.ipynb)).
It compiles all the way through to the TFlite Edgetpu format.

Now when I try to run it with the adequate script ([this](https://github.com/google-coral/pycoral/blob/master/examples/classify_image.py)) I get the following error:

> File "classify_image.py", line 76, in main
> raise ValueError('Only support uint8 input type.')
> ValueError: Only support uint8 input type.

Anybody any idea on how to fix this?